# Problema con formato de fechas en Twint y Reticulate(Libreria de R) Python

Tags: python, r, windows

Estaba intentando hacer funcionar el `scrapper` de python `Twint` dentro de `R` con la librería `Reticulate`. Uso un entorno de ejecución de anaconda, pero cuando intento usar las funciones que creé en `python` con `Reticulate` me sale este error :

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ValueError: time data 'Tue Mar 23 23:59:54 +0000 2021' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y'
```

Las funciones si corren en `Python` sin problema, quisiera saber también como podría usar un entorno virtual que no sea de anaconda con sistema operativo `Windows`.

Comment: Bienvenido Santi_Nicol a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues el código que está generando el error, aunque parece bastante claro el problema,  se estaría recibiendo una cadena con un formato distinto al esperado.